# `irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{...}[{duration}s])` returns no data in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, server, cloud, microservices, prometheus

I deploy Prometheus on my minikube cluster which has 5 nodes. I also deploy a microservice on the cluster. Prometheus can collect the data normally.

I use `wrk2` which is a workload generator to send requests to my microservices. Jaeger shows that the requests are processed normally.

The following is what confuse me. After I test the service for `duration` seconds, I try to use `sum(irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{{{constraint}}}[{duration}s])) by (container, pod)` to get the CPU usage of the pods. However, The vast majority of pods have zero CPU usage, which means no query results. I was very surprised by this because in `duration` seconds I increased the load on the service (i.e., sent a lot of requests to it), but it didn't increase the CPU usage compared to when there was no load.

Following is the python function I used to query Prometheus:

```py
# endtime=starttime+duration, starttime is the time when I start wrk2 to generate workload
def get_cpu_usage(self, starttime, endtime, duration, diaplay=False):
        # Define Prometheus query to get CPU usage for each service
        constraint = f'namespace="{self.namespace}", container!="POD", container!=""'
        prometheus_query = (
            f"sum(irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{{{constraint}}}[{duration}s])) by (container, pod)"
            + " / " + f"(sum(container_spec_cpu_quota{{{constraint}}}/({duration}*1000)) by (container, pod)) * 100"
        )

        # Send query to Prometheus endpoint
        sleep(1)
        response = requests.get(self.prometheus_url + '/api/v1/query_range', params={
            'query': prometheus_query,
            'start': starttime,
            'end': endtime,
            'step': 1
        })

        # Parse response
        usage = response.json()
        cpu_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=["microservice", "pod", "usage"])
```

Does there any bug in the code or the Prometheus setting?

Comment: What does "The vast majority of pods have zero CPU usage, which means no query results." mean? If metric has value 0 it will still return result.

Comment: Also, have you tried manually input this queries (and their parts) at Prometheus ui?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I didn't get the results of the query so I thought the value was 0 (which seems wrong). I also tried it in the web UI and got the same result as with my python script, only one or two pods had values. I also tried parts of the queries and I can get results with `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` but that value stays the same for most pods in the load test, which I think is causing `irate` to have no results. I can't understand the reason for this.

Comment: In case of Prometheus 0 and lack of result are extremely different cases. `irate` could partially be a reason of incorrect output, as it counts rate between two last samples. Try `rate` instead. But `irate` can't be a reason of lack of data.

Comment: Go through you expression step by step inside-out, and check on which step you are missing data.

Comment: So if I query by `irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{{constraint}}[{duration}s])` I should have results even though it is zero? If `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` have results but no results with `irate`, does it mean I set the wrong duration (or step) or use `irate` in the incorrect way?

Comment: Yes, you should get 0. Consider [following demo](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=irate(node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22irq%22%7D%5B1m%5D)&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22irq%22%7D&g1.tab=0&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h). It could be you've set duration to small, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change `duration` to `1m` and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus requires at least two [raw samples](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#raw-samples) on the lookbehind window specified in square brackets for calculating the [irate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#irate). Otherwise it returns an empty result.

P.S. It is recommended to use [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) instead of `irate()`, since `irate()` doesn't catch spikes. See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832) for details.